# How to convert value of optional type Binding<T?>? to Binding<T?> in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have an init like so:

```
@Binding var height: Double?

init(height: Binding<Double?>? = nil) { 
 self._height = height
}
```

I am getting an error:

> Value of optional type 'Binding<Double?>?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Binding<Double?>'

What would be the correct syntax so that I would not need to pass any value in init if it's not needed, but if I did pass the height it would then assign to the local binding variable?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to pass to the view a `Binding` that can be `nil` (so, it can be *not* bound), and bind it to a variable that cannot be `nil` (so, there *must* be something bound). Why don't you just pass a `Binding<Double?>` with a `nil` value`?

Comment: @HunterLion They both can be nil, the variable inside view is an optional. If the variable is not passed then the one inside remains nil. I don't want to always specify nil value, that is the whole point.

Comment: You are confusing optionals with default values. See my answer. What you want is a default value for the `height` parameter, not for that parameter to be an optional. You want the caller to be able to omit the `height` parameter, not for it to be an optional.

Comment: I agree on what @Paulw11 says about omission, but not necessarily about the default part. See my answer for how I think you're conflating how optionals can be used to omit arguments, with the other way you're making use of one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process of "converting" an optional to a non-optional is unwrapping.  The only way you can convert an optional to a non-optional is to provide some default value in the case where the optional is `nil`.

You have got a little confused about Swift `optional` vs default parameters.

Your problem here is you want your `height` argument to be *optional* (as in the caller doesn't need to specify it), but you shouldn't declare it as an `optional` because your object needs there to be an instance of a `Binding` - the binding must exist even though its wrapped value may be `nil`.

The type wrapped in the binding is an optional `Double` and that is what you need to provide as a default value - a binding to a `Double?`.  You can do this with `Binding.constant`

```
struct SomeView {
    @Binding var height: Double? 
    init(height: Binding<Double?> = .constant(nil)) { 
        self._height = height
    }
}
```

Now your default value is a binding to a `Double?` and the wrapped value is `nil`

If you did want your caller to be able to explicitly pass `nil` for the `height` binding then you have to deal with the default value in the initialiser itself:

```
struct SomeView {
    @Binding var height: Double? 
    init(height: Binding<Double?>? = nil) { 
        self._height = height ?? .constant(nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted. The issue now is it requires my @State var to be optional when passing. "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Double>' to expected argument type 'Binding<Double?>" How should I pass that?

Comment: You could declare your state as `@State var height:Double? =  30` so that the type matches. I think that maybe your problem is you are trying to use optionality in the wrong way. You maybe want a default height, not an optional height? Bindings to optional types can get messy

Answer (score 0):

There won't ever be a need to pass a binding to an optional. What you actually want is to be able to handle these two cases:

```swift
init(height: Binding<Double>) {
  _height = .init(height)
}

init() {
  _height = .constant(nil)
}
```

Which is closely emulated by using a default value:

```swift
init(height: Binding<Double>? = nil) {
  _height = height.map(Binding.init) ?? .constant(nil)
}
```